# Equilibrium Point problem: function returns wrong answer (-1) C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

its input:
N(size of array) = 30
A(array) = 20 17 42 25 32 32 30 32 37 9 2 33 31 17 14 40 9 12 36 21 8 33 6 6 10 37 12 26 21 3

```
        int sum = 0
        int leftSum = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
           
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            sum-=arr[j];
            if(leftSum == sum)
                return j;
            leftSum-=arr[j];
            
        }
            return -1;
```

it returns me -1

Expected Output:
13

Comment: Define `Equilibrium Point`. This code seems `C`; & will always return `-1` coz both `sum` & `leftSum` are not converging.

Comment: What programming language is this? What is the expected answer, and why?

Comment: @IMSoP i added, sorry

Comment: **Why** are you expecting 13? `leftSum` starts at `0` and you always subtract the same value from both `sum` and `leftSum` so they'll never be the same.

Comment: Please explain what this method is supposed to be doing. In particular, explain **why** you expected the result to be 13. It is not possible to tell you how to fix your code when we don't even understand what it is supposed to do. For starters, remove all your code and use just `return 13;`, then go on to tell me why that is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with :

```
leftSum += arr[j];
```

Sums need to converge, if you subtract in both places they're racing together at a distance.